# ¿Cómo comprobar existencia de caracteres desordenados?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema, tengo una función que compara la existencia de carácteres en una string, pero uso el método "includes()" y esté metodo no me vale si estos carácteres no están juntos. Es decir, con esta situación includes() me funciona y devuelve true:

```
var str = "lastCapulet"
var strConLaQueComparar: "lastCapuletPrimerCon"
```

Pero con esta no funciona. En este caso devuelve false, cuando también debería (quiero) que devuelva true.

```
var str = "apple1bat2cookie2"
var strConLaQueComparar: "apple1cookie2"
```

No hay ningún otra situación en la que va a variar más la situación, es decir, en ningún caso voy necesitar que mi función devuelva true si la str está separada en "las" "tCapulet". El caso de arriba es el de mayor "complejidad"(y el único) (en los otros están todas juntas y .includes() sirve)

He pensado en usar Regex, pero el problema es que necesito hacer esa comprobación varias veces, porque en realidad son tres `str` que están en un array. (`temporalObjCollectorArr`)

```js
for (var i=0; i<temporalObjCollectorArr.length; i++){
   if (temporalObjCollectorArr[i].includes(strConLaQueComparar)){
     FinalObjCollector.push(collection[i])
     console.log("este objeto lo enviaré a 'FinalObjCollector'")}
   else {console.log("este no lo enviaré")}
```

Comment: ¿Hay algún patrón reconocible? Por ejemplo: `lastCapuletPrimerCon` está en `camelcase`, y `apple1bat2cookie2` también tiene un patrón (separado por dígitos), tal vez puedas hacer algo si sabes el patrón. Saludos

Comment: Para ver si lo he entendido bien: ¿Con los valores `str='a123b4c5de', strConLaQueComparar='abcde'` devolvería true? ¿Y si srt fuera `'3b4c5de'`?

Comment: @PabloLozano Ahí no devolvería true. Sólo es si las dos palabras están separadas.

Comment: En los dos casos devolvería false? en el primero que puse están las 5 letras, pero separadas por números

Comment: @PabloLozano bueno, realmente me es indiferente que devolvería porque no se da nunca el caso, así que realmente si da true no me estropearía la función. El tema es que tenia un array con objetos y lo "deconstruí", entonces "lastCapulet" viene de "last: 'Capulet'" y las str almacenadas en el array que dije son también llaves y propiedades "deconstruidas" y juntadas. Claro si quiero por ejemplo comprobar si "last: 'Capulet' y "primer: "Con" " está en el array ese pero si resulta que están desordenados y no seguidos pues no me vale usar .includes()

Comment: Si están seguidos todo funciona correctamente pero un caso en que no y es dónde no estoy pasando el test

Comment: Se que pasaron 5 años, pero espero ayudar. Si hay un patrón predecible (como por ejemplo cada palabra empieza en mayusculas o está separada por un caracter especifico) se puede usar regex (regex es regular expression, expresiones regulares).  De lo contrario, la tecnica más simple, implicaría usar una base de datos con las posibles palabras ordenadas de más larga a más corta y buscar con prueba y error desde la ultima palabra encontrada.